# Static library looking for path of .winmd

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cx

I have a c++ library and it has the facility to consume it on windows run-time environment.

I want to use it as static library. I configured it that way and built it successfully.I was also able to add it's project reference to my usage.

But when i am trying to build the project where i am going to use it - I am getting build error :

```
pch.cpp : fatal error C1192: #using failed on 'D:..\mylib\mylib.winmd'
```

Why is it looking for a .winmd file? It generates .lib file. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Show us the code line.

Comment: The .winmd file is the type library for the component.  It plays the exact same role as a .h file for a normal library, it contains the declarations of the types exposed by the library.  #using is the equivalent of #include.  Trying to turn it into a static library, hmm, that ought to take a miracle or three.  I think you'd have to create your own factory functions, the ones that are now auto-generated.  *Don't do it* is the only good advice imo.

Comment: *"it has the facility to consume it on windows run-time environment"* - What facility exactly does this library have? To my knowledge, the only facility there is for a library to be consumed by a Windows Runtime language projection is a .winmd file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add below Items in my .cxproj file for making static library which get's added to my UWP as an .lib file

```
<Keyword>StaticLibrary</Keyword>
<AppContainerApplication>true</AppContainerApplication>
<ApplicationType>Windows Store</ApplicationType>        
<WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>    
<WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0
 </WindowsTargetPlatformMinVersion>
<ApplicationTypeRevision>10.0</ApplicationTypeRevision>    
<Link>
  <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
  <IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries>false</IgnoreAllDefaultLibraries>
  <GenerateWindowsMetadata>false</GenerateWindowsMetadata>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks. To be precise <GenerateWindowsMetadata>false</GenerateWindowsMetadata> is the setting that does the trick. It is a hack actually since <Link> section actually does not apply to static libs.